# Creating charts with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My code is inside a Jupyter Notebook.

I can create a chart using Method 1 below, and have it look exactly as I'd like it to look.

But when I try with Method 2, which uses subplot, I don't know how to make it look the same (setting the figsize, colors, legend off to the right).

How do I use subplot, and have it look the same as Method 1?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
#  Using Numpy and Pandas

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.style as style

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

# Colorblind-friendly colors
colors = [[0,0,0], [230/255,159/255,0], [86/255,180/255,233/255], [0,158/255,115/255]]

# Method 1
chart = df.plot(figsize = (10,5), color = colors)
chart.yaxis.label.set_visible(True)
chart.set_ylabel("Bitcoin Price")
chart.set_xlabel("Time")
chart.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
plt.show()

# Method 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df)
ax.set_ylabel("Bitcoin Price")
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just replace char by ax, like this

`ax.yaxis.label.set_visible(True)
 ax.set_ylabel("Bitcoin Price") ax.set_xlabel("Time") ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of two ways to get a result that might be useful for you. `pd.DataFrame.plot` returns an `Axes` object you can pass all the methods you want, so both examples just replace `chart` for `ax`.

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.style as style

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

# Colorblind-friendly colors
colors = [[0,0,0], [230/255,159/255,0], [86/255,180/255,233/255], [0,158/255,115/255]]
```

**Iterating over df**

```
colors_gen = (x for x in colors) # we will also be iterating over the colors
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))
for i in df: # iterate over columns...
    ax.plot(df[i], color=next(colors_gen)) # and plot one at a time
ax.set_ylabel("Bitcoin Price")
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
ax.yaxis.label.set_visible(True)
plt.show()
```

**Use pd.DataFrame.plot but pass ax as an argument**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))
df.plot(color=colors, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel("Bitcoin Price")
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
ax.yaxis.label.set_visible(True)
plt.show()
```